# FFMPEG decode render using GPU?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decode, direct3d, hardware-acceleration

My app is using FFMPEG and SDL to decode an render Videos run on WINDOWS. Decoding is using CPU

The next version, I want to Decode and Render using GPU (Hardware accelerated), and I want to using FFMPEG with Direct3D 11 for compatible all Graphics Card.

I have searched on internet during a week, but there is not any Code Sample for this.

Anyone can show me the code example?

Many thanks!

Comment: Rendering is quite trivial. For decoding, you should use DXVA.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko Not DXVA, IMFMediaEngine. Here's a complete example https://github.com/Const-me/vis_avs_dx/tree/master/avs_dx/DxVisuals/Effects/Video/MF